# Get recipient's replies with message bird

Tags: symfony, whatsapp, messagebird

When I send et WhatsApp message through the back office of my app, I wish to get the user's replies. When I try to to fetch messages from a given conversation, I only get the message sent by me, I don't get the user's replies, nor inbound messages

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the api directly??? if so it might be that you need to open a support ticket if it doesn't show when retrieved by conversation id.

If you are using php here is an example:

```
    <?php

// Retrieves a single conversation by its ID.

require(__DIR__ . '/../../autoload.php');

$messageBird = new \MessageBird\Client('YOUR_ACCESS_KEY'); // Set your own API access key here.

// Setting the optional 'include' parameter to 'content' requests the API to
// include the expanded Contact object in its response. Excluded by default.
$optionalParameters = [
    'include' => 'content',
];

try {
    $conversation = $messageBird->conversations->read(
        'CONVERSATION_ID'
    );

    var_dump($conversation);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo sprintf("%s: %s", get_class($e), $e->getMessage());
}
```

If you are getting the messages from your own service it might be that you did not setup the webhook correctly or they are disabled.
[Examples here](https://github.com/messagebird/php-rest-api/tree/master/examples/conversations)
and [here](https://developers.messagebird.com/quickstarts/conversations/handle-inbound-messages-curl/)